# How to rename subdomain name on Heroku?

Tags: url, heroku

I'm experimenting with node.js on Heroku. Just started, and saw url as: secret-shore-(number).herokuapp.com. Couldn't find in documentation, but is it possible to rename subdomain 
} else { 
do some url makeUp ?
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By renaming your app you will change its subdomain. Checkout the Heroku docs on [**renaming an app**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps). Alternatively you can rename the app in the Heroku 'My Apps' dashboard, you'll have to update your git remote locations manually as well as stated in the link.

Comment: Thomas, thank you a lot. I'm new to this (and to old for other stuff). Why I'm not so bright to find that page myself!?

Comment: You just had to look for renaming :-D